# JavaScript - Check if value is already included in an array with sub-values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that has sub-values for each value of the array and I am trying to check if a sub-value already exists within the array. Normally I would just use `array.includes()` but that isn't working in this case. How would I check for sub-values? Here's what I mean:

The array structure:
[image]

What I tried:

```js
if (dataArray.includes(`classCRN: ${classesArray[i]}`) === false) {
  // ...rest of code...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post your code / output as images. Place them within your question instead to make it easier for others to help you solve the problem. Make sure to include an example of your input, your output and your expected output. In other words: [A minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array.some() method to check it there are the same sub-values.

```
if(dataArray.some(item => item.classCRN == classesArray[i])){
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through array to find property:

```js
let arr = [
    {name: 'test', origin: 'something', value: 'bb123'},
    {country: 'Serbia', city: 'Belgrade'},
    {something: 'here', hey: 'there'}
]
console.log(isInnArray(arr,'there')) //true
console.log(isInnArray(arr,'mystring')) //false

function isInnArray(arr, findMe) {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arr[i])) {
            if(value===findMe)
                return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```